# What does Lambda Calculus teach us about data?

Tags: data-structures, lambda-calculus, computation-models

In Lambda Calculus, the distinction between data and code doesn't seem to exist. Is there something fundamental about this, or purely Lambda Calculus's thing?

Some context: as a software developer, I got used to the concept of data so much that I never considered its true nature. I'd very much appreciate any references that could help me deeper understand the role of data in computation.

Comment: The title mentions $\lambda$-calculus but the question does not. Was there anything specific about $\lambda$-calculus that you meant to ask?

Comment: @AndrejBauer If only I knew how to properly formulate the question, I'd probably be 90% on my way to the answer. Does the question make no sense at all? Unfortunately, I don't know how to formulate it better.

Comment: I think it's clearer now, although it's still difficult to guess what you're looking for, at least for me.

Comment: I've just found https://wiki.c2.com/?DataAndCodeAreTheSameThing

Comment: Ok, so for computation to happen there needs to be an input and a computational process that transforms the input into an output. The decomposition of the input into "data" and "code" components is quite arbitrary it seems.

Comment: It's not arbitrary, it's there by design. Most of the time it makes sense to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, by "arbitrary" I meant that the decomposition into "data" and "code" is only dictated by practical concerns — efficiency, ergonomics, etc. Or to put it differently, it's dictated by how we design our computational processes (calculators, stored-program computers, interpreters, virtual machines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should turn the question around and ask what *is not* data. After all, code is just more data, is it not?

Perhaps a useful view from a programming point of view is that of a *value*. Say that in a programming language a *value* is a piece of information or data which can be stored, passed around as arguments and results of functions, they can be dynamically generated at runtime, etc.

Typical types of values are `int`, `char`, `bool`, various arrays of these, lists, trees, etc. In many languages functions are *not* values. For instance, in C you cannot pass a function as an argument or return it as a result. (Caveat: a pointer to a function is not a function!) Programming languages in which functions are values are called *functional programming languages*. Examples include Haskell, OCaml, SML, scheme, racket, javascript, and many others.

We can reformulate "there is no difference beween code and data" as "functions are values". So it really is a *design choice* as to whether code should be considered data. In functional programming languages this is the case, while in many others it is not.